# I can not clone project or push it to github

Tags: git, github, connection, port

When ever i try to push or clone it showing failed to connect to proxy server

connection refused

[image]

I am new to git

how can i solve this

I checked some answers to change ssh/config file to new port but i do not have that file

Answer (score 0):

Usually the operation that I perform are

1. Generate an ssh key if you don't have already one: [instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/),
2. Add the key to github: [instructions](https://github.com/settings/keys),
3. Clone the repository via ssh: *Clone or downloading* button in the project main page,
4. Set the username or the email address for the commit messages: [instructions](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup),
5. Properly define the *.gitignore* file,
6. Have fun!!!

Consider that the ssh connection is not the only one that is available.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the anti-virus software and firewall then try it again. By the way, watch this vedio, check whether it apply to your issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmapUgg12UU